# How to move a row to bottom of sheet (GOOGLE SHEET) when “Status” is changed to a COMPLETED from OPEN

Tags: google-sheets, row, move

How to move a row to bottom of same sheet when “Status” is changed to a complete.

I'm trying to figure out how to get a row moved to the bottom once the Status B column value is changed from OPEN to CLOSED.

Sheet name is: Sheet1, Colume in which status drop down menu is at Column B, Drop down menu contain: OPEN, HOLD, PENDING, CLOSED

The trigger is need when the status changed to CLOSED

I found this code but this isnt working:

```
function onEdit(e) {

  const row = e.range.getRow();
  const col = e.range.getColumn();
  const as = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  if(as.getName() == "Sheet1" && col == 2  && row > 1 && !as.getRange(row,col).getValue()=='') {  
    const row_new = as.getRange(row,1,1,col);
    row_new.copyTo(as.getRange(as.getLastRow()+1,1,1,col));
    as.deleteRow(row);
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "isn't working"? Does it give an error? Is the output wrong?

Comment: If the answer below is not answering your question, I'd say post a copy of your sheet in case there are other errors.

Comment: Cool, The answer below worked! ONE MORE THING:  If I want to change the script to move to the top of the sheet instead of bottom then, what will be the changes? As I want the HOLD one on the top, Closed one on the bottom remaining in between. Thank you again for your assistance

Comment: If you have another question its better to open a new question instead of asking follow up questions in the comments. You should accept the answer below first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to move the entire row if the CLOSED status is selected in column B.
However, there is no check for the CLOSED status in the IF function.
In addition, not the entire row is copied, but only 2 cells:

```
const row_new = as.getRange(row, 1, 1, col)
```

If you change the code like this, then everything works well:

**Update**

You have added an additional condition about HOLD in the comments.
Here's the updated code that handles this condition as well:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const row = e.range.getRow();
  const col = e.range.getColumn();
  const as = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  const lc = as.getLastColumn();
  if(as.getName() == "Sheet" && col == 2  && row > 1 && as.getRange(row,col).getValue() == 'CLOSED') {
    const row_new = as.getRange(row, 1, 1, lc);
    row_new.copyTo(as.getRange(as.getLastRow() + 1, 1, 1, lc));
    as.deleteRow(row);
  } else if(as.getName() == "Sheet" && col == 2  && row > 1 && as.getRange(row,col).getValue() == 'HOLD'){
    as.insertRowAfter(1);
    const row_new = as.getRange(row + 1, 1, 1, lc);
    row_new.copyTo(as.getRange(2, 1, 1, lc));
    as.deleteRow(row + 1);
  }
}
```

Comment: Cool, Thanks it working, and one more thing, If I want to change the script to move to the top of the sheet instead of bottom then, what will be the changes? As I want the HOLD one on the top, Closed one on the bottom remaining in between. Thank you again for your assistance.

Comment: You're welcome. By the way, If we answered your question, please click the accept button. By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved. If the accept button is unavailable to you, feel free to tell me. https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer