# Issue with Google Apps Script not performing correcty

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

Desired result: a function that will move an entire row that contains "Ω" in column 5, to the bottom of the sheet.

I found and slightly edited this script from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66994691/how-to-move-a-row-to-bottom-of-sheet-google-sheet-when-status-is-changed-to). It essentially copies the desired row to the bottom of the sheet and then deletes that row from its current position.

The problem?  When I add the "Ω" to the cell located at (current row, column 5), it copies the row correctly and deletes it, but then also performs the script on the following row as well despite it not being edited at all. I can't tell if the issue is in the code or the issue is the size of the sheet (3000+ rows) and its slow performance is lagging the script.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const row = e.range.getRow();
  const col = e.range.getColumn();
  const sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  const lastcol = sheet.getLastColumn();

  if(sheet.getName() == "US" && col == 5  && row > 2 && sheet.getRange(row,col).getValue().includes("Ω")) {              
    var row_new = sheet.getRange(row, 1, 1, lastcol);
    row_new.copyTo(sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, 1, lastcol));
    sheet.deleteRow(row);
  }
}
```

Any help or suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: Feel free to share a link to the spreadsheet. There isn't much the volunteer contributors here can suggest when we can't see an issue live and in context.

Comment: I actually resolved my issue by switching `includes("Ω")` to `indexOf("Ω") !== -1` but I'm not certain as to why this change worked exactly.  (Also, the spreadsheet is not public as it contains business sensitive information)

Comment: I suspect it has to do with a performance and syncing of server code. I'd try to use `SpreadsheetApp.flush()` after the `sheet.deleteRow(row)`

Comment: Scratch my previous comment. It seemed to work temporarily but is back to normal. I also tried the `SpreadsheetApp.flush();` as well, but no luck.

Comment: The issue was that it was triggering two events because I had set up a trigger event previously and had forgotten about it. Totally should have checked the triggers first. So it was triggering the Simple Trigger and an additional Trigger event.