# How to move row to bottom of Google sheet for multiple tabs in a sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66994691/how-to-move-a-row-to-bottom-of-sheet-google-sheet-when-status-is-changed-to) question and answer which was helpful but I'm wondering how to apply the script (also pasted below) to multiple tabs within a sheet. The column (column 2) to check for an edit to trigger the line to move to the bottom is going to be the same on all sheets (Sheet1, Sheet2, Sheet3).

```
    function onEdit(e) {

  const row = e.range.getRow();
  const col = e.range.getColumn();
  const as = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  if(as.getName() == "Sheet1" && col == 2  && row > 1 && !as.getRange(row,col).getValue()=='') {  
    const row_new = as.getRange(row,1,1,col);
    row_new.copyTo(as.getRange(as.getLastRow()+1,1,1,col));
    as.deleteRow(row);
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Applying onEdit to multiple sheets

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  const shts = ['Sheet1','Sheet2','Sheet3'];
  const idx = shts.indexOf(sh.getName())
  if(~idx && e.range.columnStart == 2  && e.range.rowStart > 1 && e.value) {  
    const row_new = sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,1,1,e.range.columnStart);
    row_new.copyTo(sh.getRange(sh.getLastRow()+1,1,1,e.range.columnStart));
    sh.deleteRow(e.range.rowStart);
  }
}
```